# Use class of related model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, model, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to use class name of related model in laravel eloquent method by using "USE" for giving aliases to names of model classes. For example, I have used UserProfile model class:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\UserProfile;
```

And now I am using it in eloquent as follow:

```
public function profileDetails() {
    return $this->hasOne('UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

But this throws an error of `Class 'UserProfile' not found`
And If I directly pass name of the related model with path in first argument of this eloquent, then it's working fine

```
public function profileDetails() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

I'm wondering why it's not working with `use`

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.5+ you can use `UserProfile::class` (no quotes). That't the only way to take advantage of the `use` you've declared above. `use` allows you to locally alias a class, but doesn't actually change the classes fully qualified name.

Comment: @JimWright has given you the solution. because you have given wrong class path

Comment: @apokryfos It works for me. Thanks!! and there is one more way we can create an instance of this class eg. `new UserProfile`

Comment: Basically it's a local alias, whenever you'd refer to any of the classes static functions or create a new instance you can refer to it as e.g `new UserProfile` or `UserProfile::find('id')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `use` a class you are just importing it for use in that file so that you don't have to use the entire path when you want to reference it - think of it as an alias. It is also worth noting that the full class path is not the same as the relative class name in a file. The full class path will always contain the full namespace!

When you are setting up relationships Eloquent needs the full class path so that it can build objects when operating in it's own namespace. You can use `::class` on any class to get the full class path, which in your case is `App\Models\UserProfile`.

Take the following examples:

1. Eloquent will think the the relation class is `\UserProfile` which doesn't exist.

   ```
   public function profileDetails() {
       return $this->hasOne('UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
   }
   ```
2. Eloquent will look for the class `\App\Models\UserProfile` which does exist!

   ```
   public function profileDetails() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
   }
   ```
3. Eloquent will look for the class `\App\Models\UserProfile` which does exist! This is the most reliable way to reference other classes.

   ```
   public function profileDetails() {
       return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class, 'user_id', 'id');
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks!! and there is one more way we can create an instance of this class eg.  

`public function profileDetails() {
    return $this->hasOne(new UserProfile, 'user_id', 'id');
}`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that you could pass in an actual instance. Not sure what use-case there is for that but handy to know ;)